# Comments in java

Tags: java, nested, comments

I want to know how can I write something like:

```
this comment */ ends here
```

in a comment in java. I've search for an hour over the internet with no result. If I write :

```
/* this comment */ ends here */
```

then the comment would end on the first `*/`.
note that I want to use the `/* */` comment and not the `//` comment.
thanks !

Comment: Why do you  want to embed */ in comments?

Comment: I want the string this comment */ ends here - to be in a comment of type /* */

Comment: It is in a question I have from school

Comment: Did you tired with escape character?

Comment: I understand now. Elliott already gave the correct answer (you can't embed `*/` in a multi line comment).

Comment: Razib I don't have java so I can't try. the questions we have should be answerd without using java, only by looking over the internet and in the java user manual.

Comment: No the best phrasing, but I assume you are trying to put it in a generated jdoc file?

Answer (score 4):

No. You cannot embed a `*/` comment in a comment opened with `/*`. When the first `*/` is encountered the comment is closed.

Comment: well that is unfortunate isn't it. wah wah waaahhhhh. :(

Answer (score 2):

It can be done like this:

```
/** this comment &#42;/ ends here */
```

`&#42;` is the HTML character code for *, when the comment is processed into documentation, only the * will be left.

As an example:

[image]

Comment: Yes ... but from the context, the OP is clearly not talking about javadoc comments.

Answer (score 0):

The /* */ comment style absolutely requires both character pairs.  It does not allow the ending character pair except at the end of the comment.  The closest I can come to answering the question I *think* you're asking is:

```
/* this comment */
/* ends here */
```

Answer (score 0):

Since */ has a value to the language, you need to mess with */ to make it different.
Can you say...

```
this comment * / ends here
```

or

```
this comment *\ ends here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* this comment */// ends here */

/* this comment *//* ends here */

/* this comment */ /* ends here */
```